# Как получить индексы одинаковых элементов в одномереном массиве?

Tags: python, массивы

Задание:
Дан одномерный массив целых чисел. Проверить, есть ли в нем одинаковые
элементы. Вывести эти элементы и их индексы.

Написал программу, она выводит именно элементы, а как вывести индексы (именно оба индекса похожих пар) не додумался.

```
from random import random
N = 10
arr = [0] * N

for i in range(N):
    arr[i] = int(random() * 10)
print(arr)

for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        if arr[i] == arr[j]:
            print(arr[i])
            quit()
```

Пробовал метод `index`, выводит только первый индекс. Как дописать программу?

Comment: код текстом, а не картинкой, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавьте счетчик совпадений, который обнуляете перед вложенным циклом и увеличиваете, когда элементы равны. Если счетчик равен 1, то `print(arr[i], ":", i, j)`, иначе печатайте только `j`. Также добавьте множество индексов (`printed = set()`), которые уже печатали и заносите в него `i` и `j` при совпадении элементов. Естественно, выполнять вложенный цикл нужно только для тех `i`, которых еще нет в этом множестве.

Comment: @avp, зачем сет, если у него quit в цикле? А вот насчёт индексов - я бы все вхождения этого числа выводил.

Comment: Если вопрос именно про индексы, то `print(i, j)`

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что надо решать задачу -- "Вывести эти ***элементы*** и их индексы", а не следовать  ошибочной логике кода

Answer (score 0):

Первый повторяющийся элемент и все его индексы: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XYzBCsMgGIPvPkWOCv9hXbfBBvZFRg8Kltltf4s40Kd36rGQQxK@ZM/xtfFYioHGcyCcCRfClXDrvupOOPWmlbMQyxbgKcEzHP@@LpjopFEPAdh2sqIRK@UjAb8gQWvkubI1fBxLqzBhaGNgD56jTASrerbBmXcpfw)

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2, 9, 0, 5, 5, 6]

for i,x in enumerate(a):
  b = [j for j,y in enumerate(a) if x == y]
  if len(b) > 1:
    print(x, b)
    break
```

```
2 [1, 5, 6]
```

Все повторяющиеся элементы и их индексы: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITvPsUcFfZQ@wcV7LFP0JvkkECkERslGtCnT7Pbngp72Jmd@Xbe19fkTylptOhqwpFwJlwIV9nz3AgHcdhURREXy9lniBb9FLDBeeh8YOFIpPXxbYNebamrpgBcj1zrnGIBGAYM0h5o/y9wekPbYleSznK0vjQV7qi/AGAOzq/lRjDVzxEas0wjzwaVvzz0uNiUPg)

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2, 9, 0, 5, 5, 6]

use = [True for x in a]

for i,x in enumerate(a):
  if use[i]:
    b = [j for j,y in enumerate(a) if x == y]
    if len(b) > 1:
      print(x, b)
      for j in b: use[j] = False
```

```
2 [1, 5, 6]
5 [3, 9, 10]
6 [4, 11]
```